# What's the right way to run a program as a service?

Tags: services

I would like to run a grails server in the background, so that stating and stopping it would be done using:

```
sudo service my-server start
sudo service my-server stop
```

The grails server is currently executed using a shell script, which sets a few environment variables and runs grails.

What's the standard way to run this script as a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use Upstart (see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) or create a script in `/etc/init.d` (see e.g. [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html)). The former is more modern and flexible, but the latter is easier.

Comment: How do I control the script environment (for example, its PID file, the redirection of stdout and stderr)?

Comment: You will probably need to copy the contents of the grails script into the start stanza of the init.d or Upstart script and edit them to your liking. Also, some command that kills grails should go into the stop stanza. Other than that, I can't give more specific advice. Perhaps try to google for an `init.d` script or an upstart job for grails?